# How to adjust the time to connect with python bleak module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, timeout, bluetooth-lowenergy

I consulted that python bleak module allows connection and processing with ble devices. But when I try to test the developer's example but I have a problem it can search but it can't connect. I think it's due to its advertising time but I don't know how to edit it

```
import asyncio
import platform
import sys

import bleak.exc
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner
from bleak.exc import BleakError


ADDRESS = (
    "C5:66:28:34:DC:A5"
    if platform.system() != "Darwin"
    else "B9EA5233-37EF-4DD6-87A8-2A875E821C46"
)


async def main(ble_address: str):
    device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(ble_address, timeout=12.0)
    try:
        if not device:
            raise BleakError(f"A device with address {ble_address} could not be found.")
        async with BleakClient(device, timeout=12.0) as client:
            print("Services:")
            for service in client.services:
                print(service)
    except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
        print(e)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)


while True:
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))
```

This is me that I am facing. It shows as being timeout. Can u help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 213, in wait
    await fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 458, in wait_for
    fut.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\BLE_connect\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\BLE_connect\main.py", line 26, in main
    async with BleakClient(device, timeout=12.0) as client:
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\BLE_connect\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\client.py", line 61, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\BLE_connect\venv\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 249, in connect
    await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 460, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your device using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? This way you can find out if the problem really lies with your device or with your python script.

Comment: I would expect the advertising time to have no affect the connection, only the discovery. There appears to be an issue with getting services on the repo https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/1123. Looks like it is a slightly different stacktrace to yours so you might want to check with nRF Connect that it isn't a pairing issue or something like that.

Comment: I have it connected with nRF connect. But I think this is example code of bleak team dev then it will be stable. It is possible that the default parameters of the bleak module do not match this device and I need to edit it to be able to connect.

Comment: Is this the example you are using as your reference? https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/master/examples/connect_by_bledevice.py  You have put a `while True`. Have you tried running with the example from the repo with only the address changed?